# Why do the water pipes connect at the end of this loop?

Tags: plumbing

My house was built in 1905. I found this "loop" in the root cellar. Both shutoffs were completely closed but I am wondering why they would be here and why I'd want to open either one. Why would I want the hot and cold water to mix at the end of this loop?

[image]

Comment: Where does the pipe go to?  A cheap homemade sink/shower/tub setup without an actual faucet?

Comment: Is that really hot and cold? Or is it a hot recirculation loop?

Comment: It didn't go anywhere. That's the end of the room for both the hot and cold. Instead of ending at the sink above, they both T into that loop

Comment: No it's hot and cold. 6 inches before the shutoffs they both go up to the laundry sink above.

Comment: But why connect them and not just cap them?

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

To get variable temperature water at the pipe to the left. Or whatever **was** at the end of the pipe to the left at some point in time. Whether that be hot, cold, or a mixture, though "pick one" would be easier with this control setup. Some folks like to have hot water available at a hose bib, sometimes, for instance.